# Singleton data out of scope problem

Tags: objective-c, scope, singleton, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to pass data between the viewcontrollers of a uitabbarcontroller using a singleton class as below:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface AppSingleton : NSObject {

    NSMutableString *selectedStr;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableString *selectedStr;
+(AppSingleton*) sharedAppInstance;
@end
```

Here is my implementation file:

```
#import "AppSingleton.h"
@implementation AppSingleton
@synthesize selectedStr;

+(AppSingleton*) sharedAppInstance{
    static AppSingleton *sharedAppInstance;

    @synchronized(self){
        if(!sharedAppInstance){
            sharedAppInstance = [[AppSingleton alloc] init];
        }
    }

    return sharedAppInstance;
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [selectedStr release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

I try to set the selectedStr in one of my viewcontrollers as below and print it in the NSLog however I get a null:

```
    AppSingleton *sharedAppInstance;//in the header

    sharedAppInstance = [AppSingleton sharedAppInstance];//in viewdidload

[sharedAppInstance setSelectedStr:self.someStr];
        NSLog(@"selectedStr is: %@", sharedAppInstance.selectedStr);
```

When I debug this, the sharedAppInstance.selectedStr seems to be out of scope.
I would like to know where I am making a mistake.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the placing of the setting/getting of my variable within the viewcontroller and it worked..

```
[sharedAppInstance setSelectedStr:self.someStr];
        NSLog(@"selectedStr is: %@", sharedAppInstance.selectedStr);
```